# How to have Dash Plotly page update automatically with gspread data from spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, gspread

I am pulling data from a Google spreadsheet using the gspread library, and I want my Dash Plotly page to update that data. I have an input which I want to have control the kind of data being pulled. Is there a way to have the page essentially "refresh" without actually refreshing, with the new data every time the input changes?

```
html.Div(className='title', children=[
    html.H1(className='headers', children=[
        AnalysisDashboard.acell('A6').value
    ]),
    html.H2(className='headers', children=[
        'Player Report'
    ]),
    dcc.Input(id='idInput', type='number', placeholder='Enter ID'),
    html.H1(id='my-output', children=[
        'PlaceHolder'
    ])
])
```

The `AnalysisDashboard.acell('A6').value` is from the external spreadsheet, and I want that to update on the Dash Plotly page whenever I input something into the input box.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) are for.

Now I don't know in what way you want the value to change based on the input value, but based on your example it could look something like this:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    className="title",
    children=[
        html.H1(id="output", className="headers", children=["Some initial value"]),
        html.H2(className="headers", children=["Player Report"]),
        dcc.Input(id="idInput", type="number", placeholder="Enter ID"),
        html.H1(id="my-output", children=["PlaceHolder"]),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("idInput", "value"),
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    # Replace input_value with whatever you want to return 
    # like (AnalysisDashboard.acell('A6').value) or something similar
    return input_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```